# Postgres select queries inside a transaction is slow

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, postgres-12

What could be the reason that select queries performed inside a transaction is really slow
even though the queries are with just their primary key?

I have two tables after updating one row in table1 the query in table2 within the same transaction is really slow
even though the query on table2 is just

```
select * from table2 where id = 10
```

table1 and table2 have a lot of rows

Comment: Either a concurrent statement like `ALTER TABLE` that locks the table against queries, or terribly low storage, or a network problem.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe no ALTER TABLE were running at that time

Comment: Try to get an `EXPLAIN (ANALYZE, BUFFERS)` under both conditions.

Comment: If it is a test database and you did many operations already , open your PSQL and run the command inside of the database: VACUUM ;